# Aurelia bundling and transpiling

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, aurelia

I'm currently trying to bundle an Aurelia app for "production". I tried using `$ aurelia bundle`, or now with gulp; which is quite the same. But I'll always have

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```

In my `index.html`, which mean that I have to upload jspm packages on my server (ok, not all maybe), and that Babel's 1.9mb `browser.js` file will be loaded in the browser and only then it will transpilate. It can be pretty long.

Is there any way to get a bundled-transpiled-minified file? Does it make sense?
Thanks a lot!

Here's my config (in my gulpfile.js)

```
  bundles: {
    "src/dist/app-bundle": {
      includes: [
        '*',
        'aurelia-bootstrapper',
        'aurelia-fetch-client',
        'aurelia-router',
        'aurelia-templating-binding',
        'aurelia-templating-resources',
        'aurelia-templating-router',
        'aurelia-loader-default',
        'aurelia-history-browser',
        'aurelia-auth'
      ],
      options: {
        inject: true,
        minify: true
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand how `system.js` and `config.js` implies needing `browser.js` or even any jspm packages?

In order to load system.js, you only need the files in the top-level of jspm_packages (on my system, currently, that is system.js, system-csp-production.js, and system-polyfills.js)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have `runtime` option for babel enabled where babel is only transpiling your JavaScript at runtime instead of at development time.

If you set your bundle to be `inject`ed at runtime instead of transpiled then it should be much faster and a smaller footprint.

Comment: I remove the "runtime" option in my config.js, but the browser.js file is still loaded. I added my bundle config in the question.